# Can I create a Stripe subscription through code in Zapier?

Tags: javascript, python, stripe-payments, zapier

I'm using Zapier and Stripe to sign our users up for licenses and generating keys through Keygen.sh.

However, if one user would like to purchase multiple licenses, I'm currently handling this through a for loop, creating many new subscriptions in Stripe. This works great, however, a new invoice is created for each subscription, which is something I need to avoid. Creating a subscription manually allows you to set the quantity.

Since the "Create Subscription" Action in Zapier is missing the quantitiy field, I wanted to move to creating subscriptions through the Stripe API via code allowing me to access the missing quanity-field. The "Code" Action in Zapier however does not allow me to import the Stripe library. Only the default JS/Python modules can be used.

I realize I might have to look to another direction to get the intended behaviour set up. I would be very thankful if someone could guide me in the right direction.

EDIT;
SOLVED
I did not realize that you can create custom Zap Actions using https://developer.zapier.com/. This allowed me to create custom web requests. In my case i created the license manually through the stripe API via a custom Zapier action.